# Index not compiling with the -output-directory option

Tags: indexing, output

I have a minimal working example of my main latex file `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12 pt, oneside]{book}

% ________________________________Packages_________________________________
\usepackage[margin=1 in]{geometry} % Adds 1 inch margins 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  % Allows the addition of headers to each page
\usepackage{amsthm}

% For index
\usepackage{imakeidx} 
\makeindex[options = -s pyro, columns = 2, intoc]

% ________________________________Document_________________________________
\begin{document}
% ________________________________Contents_________________________________
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
% __________________________________Body___________________________________
\index{This} This text is some text placed here.

\newpage
\index{Here} Here is some additional text.

% ________________________________Ending____________________________________
\printindex % Puts the index chapter here
\end{document}
```

In the same directory, I have another file called `pyro.ist` which is used to modify the index page to my liking. The code for this file is below:

```
heading_prefix "\n\\noindent\\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}\\par\\nopagebreak\n"
```

Using a mac, on the terminal, if I compile my `main.tex` document with the following command

```
pdflatex -shell-escape -file-line-error main.tex | grep .*:[0-9]*:.*
```

the index is printed and is visible in the contents. (Note that you may have to compile twice for the index to be visible for some reason). I also have the following message on the terminal:

```
This is makeindex, version 2.16 [TeX Live 2022] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file ./pyro.ist...done (3 attributes redefined, 0 ignored).
Scanning input file main.idx....done (2 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Sorting entries....done (2 comparisons).
Generating output file main.ind....done (13 lines written, 0 warnings).
Output written in main.ind.
Transcript written in main.ilg.
```

Now, within that same working directory, I made a new directory called `output`.
I deleted all the output files (`main.aux`, `main.idx`, `main.log`, `main.toc`, `main.ilg`, `main.ind`).
The only files in the directory that were kept are `main.tex`,`pyro.ist`, and the directory `output`.
However, if I compile my `main.tex` by the following command

```
pdflatex -shell-escape -output-directory=output -file-line-error main.tex | grep .*:[0-9]*:.*
```

and open the `main.pdf` file in the `output` directory, the index page is not being printed.
I get the following message on the terminal:

```
Input index file main.idx not found.
Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]
system returned with code 256
```

Why is it if I re-direct the output files to the `output` directory that the index is having problems?

Comment: naturally if you configure tex to write files to a non standard place you need to configure makeindex (and everything else) to find them. It is possible of course, but far simpler not to use `-output-directory` (I never use it)